# why am I getting (self: ) when I make function?

Tags: ios, swift, function

```
struct StoryBrain {
    var storyNumber = 0


    let Allstory = [
        Story(s: "There is a fork on the road", c1: "Take a left", c2: "Take a right"),
        Story(s: "There are two door", c1: "Enter the left door", c2: "Enter the Right door"),
        Story(s: "You can have either a dog or a cat", c1: "I will have a dog", c2: "I will have a cat")
    ]

    func getStory() ->String {
        return Allstory[storyNumber].mainStory
    }
    func getchoice1() -> String {
        return Allstory[storyNumber].choice1
    }
    func getchoice2() -> String {
        return Allstory[storyNumber].choice2
    }
```

This is Model

in view controller, I want to make updateUI function

```
func updateUI() {
    storyLabel.text = StoryBrain.getStory(self: StoryBrain)
```

I do not understand why I am getting (self: StoryBrain) instead of just ().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are not static or class methods ... you need to create object of that class to call its functions sir ... or make them static/class functions if you dont want to create object of that class

Either do

```
func updateUI() {
  let story = StoryBrain()
  storyLabel.text = story.getStory()
 }
```

Or you can make them static to use but thats not a good approach

```
struct StoryBrain {
   static var storyNumber = 0


   static let Allstory = [
        Story(s: "There is a fork on the road", c1: "Take a left", c2: "Take a right"),
        Story(s: "There are two door", c1: "Enter the left door", c2: "Enter the Right door"),
        Story(s: "You can have either a dog or a cat", c1: "I will have a dog", c2: "I will have a cat")
    ]

   static func getStory() ->String {
        return Allstory[storyNumber].mainStory
    }
   static func getchoice1() -> String {
        return Allstory[storyNumber].choice1
    }
  static  func getchoice2() -> String {
        return Allstory[storyNumber].choice2
    }
```

Now you can do

```
func updateUI() {
    storyLabel.text = StoryBrain.getStory()
  }
```

Comment: I am really sorry but I am new to this. I do know how to fix it. Can you write a code?  so I may be able to understand it

Comment: Do ... let story =  StoryBrain() .,, then story.getStory()

Comment: Or write the function with static keyword

Comment: Static func getStory() ->String {

Comment: Thank you very much. I meant I don't know how to fix it. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Because `getStory()` is not marked as `static`.

Answer (score 0):

You declaring `getStory` as an instance method. So you need to call it on an instance of `StoryBrain`, that is what the compiler is trying to tell you with `self` there.

```
let storyBrain = StoryBrain() // create an instance
storyLabel.text = storyBrain.getStory() // call the instance method on that instance
```